# Combining Two MySQL Queries with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The below code is simple PHP/MySQL script that returns the results of a single MySQL query utilizing PHP. When looking for particular results within my database, it would sometimes be simpler to join multiple queries utilizing PHP. If for example I wanted to join a secondary query to the below code, what PHP script would be used to do this? One example is I did a query utilizing subqueries with LEFT JOINs as one query. I would like to get the same results as that query only doing it by joining multiple queries through PHP.

I have looked for answers to this, but I don't think I know how to phrase it correctly since I just get results on how to do MySQL JOIN operations.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "marketing");
$result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT INDV_FIRST_NAME, INDV_LAST_NAME
    FROM INDV_INDIVIDUAL
    LIMIT 100
");
if (!$result) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
    exit;
}
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['INDV_FIRST_NAME'] . $row['INDV_LAST_NAME'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `$mysqli->query()` statement will execute only one query. To accomplish your needs, you can write a query using a [subselect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) or execute two separate `$mysqli->query()` statements.

Comment: mysqli has multi query support: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @George Cummins the subselect is what I did prior to utilizing PHP. It worked, but also wanted to know how to accomplish the same thing utilizing PHP. I'll check out the manual. A friend of mine also mentioned utilizing arrays and a while or for loop